# Send fullscreen message to multiple firefox windows in xmonad

Tags: firefox, xmonad

Consider multiple opened firefox windows in a tiled view in xmonad. How can I make all windows "fullscreen" (inside its tile) (i.e. equivalent to going to the tile and pressing f11) at once?